# When putting a UITableView in a UICollectionViewCell do I need to update the UI of the tableViewCell on a different thread?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

As the title states I'm having problems reloading the UITableView within each UICollectionViewCell. I have two prototype cells, one with text and the other with an image that gets populated by a request from the server. When i select the image cell it loads the correct prototype cell correctly, but if I don't select it, then it shows the wrong prototype cell. Now, I'm guessing that I need to update the UI on another thread, does anyone know if this is the correct way of handling this situation? Any advice?

Comment: You should *never* update UI in a secondary thread. UI updation always has to happen in main thread. In this case, whenever model related to your cell changes, ensure you do a 'reloadData' on the table related.

Comment: @Shripada When dequeueing every single UICollectionViewCell, before I return the cell, I have a function which reloads the UITableView in that corresponding UICollectionView. It is the only way I am able to see the tableview updated. Any other suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You should post relevant code here as this is most likely a programming error. It's very unlikely that this issue is related to threading.